# Which key instance is retained by a Map if the entry already exists?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

Consider the following map:

```
Map<Foo,Bar> fooBarMap = new Map<Foo,Bar>();
```

And the following two instances of Foo, foo1 and foo2:

```
foo1 != foo2
foo1.equals(foo2)
```

(i.e. they are separate but equivalent). Now, consider the following insertions:

```
fooBarMap.put(foo1,bar1);
fooBarMap.put(foo2,bar2);
```

**Question: which key is retained? Does foo2 replace foo1?**

Put another way, does putting the same key twice update the key and value, or just the value?

(If you're wondering why I'm asking, it's because I'm using a WeakHashMap and must make sure I don't release references prematurely).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: "If you're wondering why I'm asking, it's because I'm using a WeakHashMap and must make sure I don't release references prematurely"

Comment: I would say that, if the behavior is not stated in the spec, you cannot depend on it, one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Sun/Oracle implementation of HashMap does the following.

With this statement sequence:

```
map.put(foo1, "bar1");
map.put(foo2, "bar2");
```

If foo2 and foo1 have the same hashCode(), and either (foo2 == foo1) or (foo2.equals(foo1)) then:

- the existing key (foo1) will be retained, but
- its mapped value will be changed to "bar2"

*Aside: (foo2 == foo1) does not imply (foo2.equals(foo1)), because not all equals() implementations perform the '==' test -- even though they should. Also, (foo2.equals(foo1)) does not imply (foo1.equals(foo2))!*

Comment: But any equals method that didn't find an object equal to itself would be prima-facie defective.

Comment: @HotLicks: True, and there are a lot of defective equals() and hashCode() implementations out there. It is actually not easy to get right: http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html.

Answer (score 2):

This sample code:

```
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    final String foo1 = new String("foo");
    final String foo2 = new String("foo");
    map.put(foo1, "bar");
    map.put(foo2, "bar");
    System.out.println(map.keySet().iterator().next() == foo1);
    System.out.println(map.keySet().iterator().next() == foo2);
```

prints:

```
true
false
```

It seems pretty logical, since the `.keySet()` of a `Map` is a `Set`, and a `Set` will not replace a value which is already has. The [javadoc for `Set`'s `.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) says that it:

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation).

Note that the "optional operation" is because the doc also says that `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown if the `Set` implementation does not support addition.

Comment: Thank you! However I never said bar1 is equal or equivalent to bar2. I will try your code with different values.

Comment: Doesn't change anything ;) Again, what matter is the `Set` contract here, and `Map`'s `.keySet()` is a `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the Map implementation. Most implementations that I've seen will keep the first key, because the logic tends to be "find the entry by the key, and if it exists, update the value in the entry", i.e. it doesn't over-write the key ref.